# What is the meaning of tehom?

Tags: hebrew, words, water

Throughout the Tanach, and I've seen it in Midrashim as well, there is a concept of the "Tehom", translated as "Deep Waters". It appears in the creation story in Bereishis, and in the song at Yam Suf. It appears throughout Tehillim.

What is this?

I read a Midrash that King David was digging for the Temple and went too deep and the Tehom erupted, threatening to flood the entire world.

Comment: You talking about this gemara http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=11&format=pdf ?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30455&pgnum=54

Comment: Yes, but its just one example.

Comment: It is 'the murmuring deep' to quote the title of a book by Avivah Zornberg (taking the root to be heh vav mem, which can mean to murmur.)

Answer (score 5):

A "tehom" is merely a large gathering of water (Radak, Shorashim, erech תהם (p. 48 [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/radak/radak07.pdf))).

Comment: That's the meaning of the word but what is the concept about? It appears throughout Tanach and can't merely just be describing a large gathering of water....Tehom is refered to before the earth was created, what does this mean? What does the midrash mean that the world has inside it Tehom that will flood the world?

Comment: @robev, your question above asks what _t'hom_ **is**. This is a good answer. If you seek clarification of any particular _pasuk_ or _midrash_, please [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: My question included his answer though, so he didn't add anything I didn't know already. I'm not asking about a particular pasuk or midrash, I'm asking for the explanation of the term that appears throughout Torah, not just it's translation. It appears in many places in a cryptic way so it's obviously more than just "water".

Comment: @robev That was what I was addressing with my answer: The Radak is usually thorough in his explanations of shorashim, and his omission implies that this is all that it is (note the "merely" in my answer)

Comment: I don't doubt the Radak is giving the best explanation as to what the shoresh means, but I'm asking what the use of the word means in Torah. An example would be the gemarrah expression "af al pi", which literally means nose on mouth. I'm not interested in the literal translation I want the explanation of the phrase (in my example it is "nevertheless")

Answer (score 4):

Researching a possible connection between sub-seafloor hydrated methane and the Biblical Leviathan a few years ago I gathered the following impression of the tehom: 
Subterranean waters -- waters beneath the Earth's surface -- the waters beneath the waters -- place of imprisonment for 6/7th of the Leviathan (1/6th -- the Behemoth -- bound in/by the surface waters and green plants). Nahmanides and Maimonides came up frequently.

". . . the earth was tohu vavohu and darkness was upon the face of the tehom and the ruach elohim hovered over the face of the waters.” Genesis 1:2

In light of recent geologic discoveries, tehom fits the description of the subterranean ocean containing three times the volume of Earth's surface seas and located some 400 miles beneath the crust. Under enormous pressure bound up in a porous rock called ringwoodite. Sounds like a likely source for the "fountains of the great deep" God broke up in Noah's time.

Comment: Welcome to the site Mike. Awesome answer. I was wondering if your research was available anywhere? sounds really fascinating!

Answer (score 0):

Re. "What does the midrash mean that the world has inside it Tehom that will flood the world?"

Seems to refer here to the indwelling presence of God -- as God -- at the heart of all creation that will upwell and manifest at the Great Day of the LORD.

Answer (score -1):

The Water was gathered from the ground and stored sorta say into the tehomah .

From Sefer  בצרור החיים:

״קפא תחומא נעא למישטפא לעלמא״ - כתב רש״י במסכת סוכה (נג,ב
 ד״ה אחספא) מפרש ״ובאגדת דספר שמואל שמצא דוד [חרס] על פני נקב
 התהום וכתוב בו [על החרס] שהיה שם מששת ימי בראשית״. ובשינוי ק צ ת
 במסכת מכות (יא,א ד״ה קפא) ״ מ מ ר ת  ירושלמי ;שם) שמצא שם חרס
 י שהגביה קולו ואמר לו אל תטלני מכאן שאני כ מ ש  על התהום מיום מתן תורה
 שרעדה כל הארץ, ולא שמע דוד לדבריו ונטלו״.
 והיינו שהחרס היה ממש על נקג חתהום, וע״י נטילתו ־ באופן טבעי - עלה
 התהום לשטוף את העולם.

נ ,
 נעא למישנזפא לעלמא
 אמנם צ״ל הלשון בעא למישטפא לעלמא [רצח לשטוף א ת  העולם],
 שמשמע שאינו כתוצאה מנטילת חחרס וממילא עלו המים אלא שזהו ענין
 רציני.
 עיין במהרש״א חד״א (סוכה נג,א) שמבאר בביאור נפלא כללות הסוגיא.
 ולהלן נקודה מדבריו חקי:
 ״לפי טבע מהראוי שיהיו גם המים עולות על הארץ... והשם יתברך
 במאמרו כעס המים ונתנן באוצר התהום [וכפי שמבואר במסכת חגיגה] אמר
 ריש לקיש בשעה שברא הקב״ה עולמו הים היה מרחיב והולך עד שגער בו
 הקב״ה מ ׳  [ומפרש המהרש״א] פירוש, שהיה הים מרחיב והולך לפי טבעו על
 הארץ עד שגער בו הקב״ה וכנס אותו למקום אחד באוצר התהום... וכשבא דוד
 ורצה לכרות היסודות של ביהמ״ק עד התהום גילה נקב התהום וכיסויו שהוא
 העציץ שהיה מונח וכבוש שם במעשה בראשית... סליק תהומא למקומו הטבעי
 לישטף עלמא כטבעו להיות על הארץ עד שכתב שם על החספא וחשב להניח
 אותו על נקב התהום שבאותו מאמר השם שהיה כתוב על החספא כבשו המים
 לירד לתהום״.

ובספר עיון יעקב [על העין יעקב](מכות יא,א) מוסיף ביאור(כהנ״ל) וכותב
 ״אפשר לומר לפי שאז נתבסס העולם מ ה  שנברא בששת ימי בראשית וכדאיתא
 בפסיקתא והובא בילקוט(מלכים א סימן ז)... כיון שבנה שלמה ביהמ״ק אמר
 הקב״ה עכשיו שלמה מלאכת שמים וארץ לכך נקרא שלמה ע״ש [כלומר:
 ששלמה המלך נקרא בשם שלמת מפני שהוא תשלים מלאכת שמים וארץ].
 וכמו שבתחלת בריאת שמים וארץ בקשו לשטוף א ת  העולם עד שגער בהם
 הקב״ה... אף כך תחלת בנין בית המקדש בעי למשטפיה לעלמא עד שכתבו
 השם״ [אחספא].

Comment: This doesn't help me....

Comment: why not because it is not translated or because of the content?

Comment: its not translated or explained